# Express width as a function of area

Tags: functions

a simple math problem that I've been cracking my head over.

Let $L, W$, and $A$ denote the length, width and area of a rectangle, respectively, and suppose that the width of the rectangle is half the length.

If $W$ is expressed as a function of $A$, then $W=$?
The answer is $\sqrt{A/2}$ but how do I go about obtaining it?

I know that $W = L/2$, and $A = L^2 /2$, and that $W =$ Area / Length. 
So based on the above, i can safely say that (Area / Length) $= L/2 $
And this is where i get stuck. If i use the model answer $\sqrt{A/2}$ i can simplify it to obtain $L/2$. But what is the proper way to go about obtaining $\sqrt{A/2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the fact that

> the width of the rectangle is half the length

in order to express $l$ in terms of $w$,
i.e. $$l = 2w,$$
Now you know that the area of a rectangle is length*width so you can write
$$A = wl$$ 
substituting by the above equation we get 
$$A= w(2w) = 2w^2.$$ 
Stays to express $w$ in terms of $A$, noting that $A,l,w \geq 0$ we get:
$$A=2w^2 \iff \frac{A}{2} = w^2 \iff \sqrt\frac{A}{2} =w.$$

Comment: ARGH its so simple!!! I spend over an hour and a half trying to figure it out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let us use $l,w,A$  respectively for the length, the width and the area of the rectangle.

As, you know $A=l \times w$ and in your case $w=\frac{l}{2}$ that is to say $l=2w$; so $A=2w^2$ and then ..

I am sure that you can take from here.